# Symfony2 doctrine form - entity type

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to add an entity field in a symfony2 form but it's always giving me the same error: '500 (Internal Server Error) '.

This is the class i'm using to create the form. It was automatically programmed with doctrine and CRUD.

```
class ClientType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('companyName', 'text' , array( 'attr' => array( 'class' => 'companyname' ) ) )
            ->add('contactUserName','text' , array( 'attr' => array( 'class' => 'contactusername' ) ))
            ->add('phone','text' , array( 'attr' => array( 'class' => 'phone' ) ))
            ->add('subdomain','text' , array( 'attr' => array( 'class' => 'subdomain' ) ))
            ->add('email','text' , array( 'attr' => array( 'class' => 'email' ) ))
            ->add('website','text' , array( 'attr' => array( 'class' => 'website' ) ))

         ;

    }
```

This works fine, but then, i try something like this:

```
->add('client', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'BackendBundle:Client'));
```

'500 (Internal Server Error)'

I tried so many different ways to do this, but it's always the same error.
The thing is, i can add or remove the fields that were created at the beggining when this class was done by the doctrine CRUD but if i try adding more fields with different types, it won't let me.

Should i make my own Type class so i can customize my forms or is there a way to modify the form doctrine made?

TY

Comment: Switch to development mode to get more useful error messages.

Comment: This may seem obvious, but do you know that each field you add must exist as a property in the Client class, with the appropriate set method?

Comment: please provide the entity model definition

Answer (score 1):

> The thing is, i can add or remove the fields that were created at the
>   beggining when this class was done by the doctrine CRUD but if i try
>   adding more fields with different types, it won't let me.

This is because the command that created your `ClientType.php` did so, based upon the structure of your `BackendBundle\Entity\Client.php` file. The form is mapped to the entity that you intend to create. If you want more fields on the form, you will need to add the fields as properties in your `BackendBundle\Entity\Client.php`, then run:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities <VENDOR>/<BUNDLE>/Entity/Client

or if using Symfony 2 < version 2.5

php app/console doctrine:generate:entities <VENDOR>/<BUNDLE>/Entity/Client
```

To generate the getters and setters for that field, and then

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force 

or if using Symfony 2 < version 2.5

php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

To add the new field(s) to the database table.

Now you can try to add the field as you were, ensuring that the first argument in the `add()` method exactly matches how you names your property in the entity.

Comment: I'd understand that if i would like to add a field that is not in my client class, but when i try the code "$builder->add('client', 'entity', array('class' => 'BackendBundle:Client'));", removing all the previous 'add'  i'm not adding anything new to the class, they are the same fields but im calling them all together instead of doing it one by one.
As far as i know, the class don't store the type of the form's input. 
Then, i want to show a field that is already in the class but, instead of using a 'text' type i want to use 'entity' or 'choice' or whatever. It wont let me either.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you can do that, or why you would want to

Comment: I just cannot use any other type of form field than the 'text' one. That's the main problem. I've added the rest of the information to compose a good question, but that's what i want to solve. 
Could it be because of the doctine CRUD? Depending on the answer i'll keep researching on one direction or another.